# Google Spreadsheet add-on does not deploy when using "deploy from manifest" method

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, add-on

I have used add-ons for Spreadsheets for 5 years. I used to deploy them from the Chrome Web Store. The recent changes made by Google make it very difficult to get past the OAuth authorization process, so I would like to revert to an installation simply for the user. I cannot make that work.

Spreadsheet add-ons are now part of "editor add-ons". It's always possible to test them from the "test as add-on" menu ([ref here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons)), but this is very impractical if you need to test extensively on all sorts of documents, and share the testing with other users.

The "GSuite add-ons" (ie NOT for spreadsheets) have a method described [there](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons) to deploy without going through the webstore.

Is there a similar way to deploy Spreadsheet add-ons over your own user's Drive without jumping through the hoops of OAuth authorizations?

Code snippet of a simplified project, that actually requires minimal authorization.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  Logger.log('Starting add-on onOpen')
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var myMenu = ui.createAddonMenu()
  myMenu.addItem('Hello add-on', 'hello')
  myMenu.addToUi();
}

function hello(){
  Browser.msgBox('Hello add-on')
}
```

This works in the "test as add-on" environment
But impossible to deploy without resorting to the GSuite Marketplace.

Your help will be very much appreciated, I have thousands of lines of code that are not usable for that reason.

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: Hello! Is "Deploy from Manifest" a valid solution for you?

Comment: Hi, "Deploy from Manifest" works for "GSuite add-ons", i.e not for Spreadsheets according to documentation (the naming is very confusing, they are now "editor add-ons"). I still tried "Deploy from Manifest", but could not get it it to work. Thx

Comment: I see. Are you a G Suite user? G Suite users can deploy addons for their Domain without going through Google's authorization.

Comment: Hi Jescanellas, confirmed, in the GSuite environment, I do that without the marketplace, through the admin console. My question is here for a basic GMail user. I had Google support on the phone in the meantime, and they have confirmed this is a gap. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "jumping through the hoops of authorization"?

Comment: The OAuth authorization process requires a large number of elements (homepage, terms of use, app demonstration video, security assessment, scope verification). In the end it is up to the moderators. In the case of my complete app, the required scopes are email
profile
openid
../auth/script.container.ui
../auth/documents
../auth/drive
../auth/gmail.readonly
../auth/script.scriptapp
../auth/gmail.send
../auth/spreadsheets
../auth/script.external_request, and this seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want other users apart from yourself to find the Add-on and install it. This will require the Add-on to be examined by Google to ensure it meets all requirements and guidelines for public Add-ons.

The only way to install a script as Add-on without Google examining it, is to deploy it from the manifest file. Which you would have to share with your test users.

You can allow other users to test the add-on by sharing the Apps Script project with their account (read access is required) and then prompting the users to follow the [steps outlined here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/testing-gsuite-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on).

Once installed, the add-on is immediately available in host applications it extends. *Keep in mind users must also authorize the add-on before using it.*

You can share it with as many test users as you want before publishing it.

---

**References:**

- [Extending Sheets with Add-Ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. The procedure you point at is for "GSuite add-ons" and not "Editor add-ons". Yes, very confusing. A spreadsheet add-on is an "Editor add-ons"

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed not possible by the Google support team:

> After checking internally with the GSM team I can confirm that creating an internal Add-on to be used within multiple documents is not supported at this time for non GSuite users. Performing this with a GSuite account is very simple as you can create your Add-on script and publish privately for your domain only. Standard Gmail accounts do not support this. We highly recommend to work from a GSuite account since it will give you extended possibilities in the publishing and distribution of Add-ons.
>
> Some workarounds you can use at this time:
>
> - Copy your codebase to a container bound script bound to a sheet. You can do this into any other sheet you want your code to work with. You can also share the sheet with other users, and ask all your users to copy the sheet for their use.
> - Go ahead and publish the Add-on with public visibility (maybe 'unlisted') but you will have to go through the OAuth verification as the item is set to be public. When you engage with the OAuth verification process you will need to tell them that this is meant for a Public Add-on instead of a Private one.

My prefered workaround is similar to the one proposed, except I use the former add-on standalone script as a library, which I call from the container-bound script.